# Creating ObservableCollection from class

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a WPF app with an event log.  I have an EventLog class I populate with saved events from an XML file when the app starts

```
namespace MyApp.Agent.EventLogging
{
    public enum EventType
    {
        Infomation,
        Error
    }
    public class EventLog
    {
        public String Image { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public String EventText { get; set; }
    }
}

public List<EventLog> GetSavedEvents()
{
   string file = XmlUtilities.GetXmlLocation() + "\\Events.xml";
   List<EventLog> elog = new List<EventLog>();
   try
   {
       if (File.Exists(file))
       {
          Serialize<List<EventLog>> ser = new Serialize<List<EventLog>>();
          elog = ser.DeserializeDocToObj(file);
       }
   }
   catch
   {
          throw new InvalidEventLogException(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EventLogFileInvalid"));
   }
 return elog;
}
```

I then convert this into an observable collection that a listview is bound to

```
List<EventLog> _evtLog = new List<EventLog>();
ObservableCollection<EventLog> _eventLog = new ObservableCollection<EventLog>();
_evtLog = logger.GetSavedEvents();
_evtLog.ForEach(x => _eventLog.Add(x));
```

I read that this is how it has to been done (although it seems a long winded way)

As the app is running new events are added to the observable collection. When the app closes I reverse this process to save the events.

While this works fine if there are only a few saved events as the list is getting bigger so the time it takes to do this is getting unrealistic (240K events is taking 7 secs). Ok first question you may ask is why would I want that many events anyway, truth is I don't but it does highlight that I am not doing this the best way?

So my questions are:

Do I really need to populate the observable collection? Can I not make `_evtLog` Observable without populating one from the other?

Can I restrict these lists to X events based on the date of the event?

Comment: Are you creating a new observable collection every time a new log is added? by the way you can do it this way ObservableCollection<EventLog> _eventLog = new ObservableCollection<EventLog>(logger.GetSavedEvents()); as you are doing it, the collection is firing a collection changed event every time you add an item so 240k collection chaned events i'm not surprised this is taking a lot

Comment: After reading your problem is not the observable collection. Instead it is the de-/serialize process. Are these 240k events are needed within the file? If not, simply cut the list after deserializing and after each add of a new event to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily change `GetSavedEvents` to serialize and deserialize an `ObservableCollection<EventLog>` instead of a `List<EventLog>`.

Having said that, the code to convert the list to an observable collection looks strange. Why aren't you just using the appropriate constructor?

```
_eventLog = new ObservableCollection<EventLog>(logger.GetSavedEvents());
```

The problem with using `Add` is that for each item being added you raise an event.

Comment: Perfect! I still have to limit the list but 250K events now load instantly. Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 2):

following will create `ObservableCollection`

```
var _eventLog = new ObservableCollection<EventLog>(logger.GetSavedEvents());
```

regarding filtering your results, yes you can do a quick `LINQ` select query where you define the restrictions and get the results as a `List` which you'll pass to `ObservableCollection`

**some idea's on filtering results**

you might need some tweaking depending on your needs

```
var _eventLog = new ObservableCollection<EventLog>(logger.GetSavedEvents().where(event => event.date == some date).ToList());
```

Comment: check the updated post, added a little sample on filtering results

Comment: Could I use this filtering to select only the TOP X ordered by event date?

Comment: Sure: `logger.GetSavedEvents().OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate).Take(X)`

Comment: From what I can see this is working but it returns an IOrderedEnumerable and I then have to convert the result of this into my `ObservableCollection<EventLog>`  From what I have read I have to loop thorugh one list adding it to the other?

Comment: Got it.  Just in case anyone stumbles on this.

`var el = logger.GetSavedEvents().OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate).Take(X)` 

`_eventLog = new ObservableCollection<EventLog>(el);`   Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the actual code that generates the ObservableCollection? Generating an OC from a 240k element list should NOT take 7 seconds, it should be nearly instantaneous.

Are you sure you are not adding events to a collection that is already bound to a listview, causing the listview to be updated for each item?

Try using this instead of ObservableCollection:

```
class MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool _notifyCollectionChanged = true;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_notifyCollectionChanged)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _notifyCollectionChanged = false;
        foreach (T element in collection)
            Add(element);
        _notifyCollectionChanged = true;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

And add the List to the ObservableCollection using oc.AddRange(list).

If this doesn't help, then your GetSavedEvents function is probably what is running for 7 seconds, and it has nothing to do with the ObservableCollection.